# How to use Internationalization in tornadofx

Tags: kotlin, internationalization, tornadofx

I am trying to use internationalization in a Kotlin application using the tornadofx framework.

I have created a properties file and depending on the selected language the correct file is loaded. But when I want to change the language in the running application the UI does not update accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

For internationalization you should use a companion object to get the related translation anywhere in your application.
First of all your translation class should know which is the actual selected language/locale. For this I use an enum with the possible locales for the application:

```
fun setLocale(locale: SupportedLocale) {
  if (SupportedLocale.supportedLocals.contains(locale)) {
    Locale.setDefault(locale.local)
    actualLocal = locale.local
    //Good practice would be to store it in a properties file to have the information after restart
  } else {
    //Throw a warning or sth with your preferred logger
  }
}
```

Then we need a method which gets the particular string value from your resource bundle like:

```
operator fun get(@PropertyKey(resourceBundle = BUNDLE_NAME) key: String, vararg args: Any): String {
        val bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME, actualLocal)
        return MessageFormat.format(bundle.getString(key), *args)
    }
```

In JavaFx applications (also TornadoFX) you should use StringBindings (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/StringBinding.html) for example to bind a label text property to your translated string. For that we will implement a special method:

```
fun createStringBinding(@PropertyKey(resourceBundle = BUNDLE_NAME) key: String, vararg args: Any): StringBinding {
        return Bindings.createStringBinding(Callable { get(key, *args) }, Settings.languageProperty())
    }
```

Now you can use your object like this:

```
textProperty().bind(MyLang.createStringBinding("MyApp.MyTranslation"))
```

Here an runnable example:

MyLang.kt

```
enum class SupportedLocale(val local:Locale) {
ENGLISH(Locale.ENGLISH),
GERMAN(Locale.GERMAN);

  companion object {
    val supportedLocals: List<SupportedLocale>
        get() = SupportedLocale.values().toList()
  }
}

class MyLang {
    companion object {
        private const val BUNDLE_NAME = "Language" //prefix of your resource bundle
        private var actualLocal = Locale.getDefault()

        fun setLocale(locale: SupportedLocale) {
          if (SupportedLocale.supportedLocals.contains(locale)) {
            Locale.setDefault(locale.local)
            actualLocal = locale.local
            //Good practice would be to store it in a properties file to have the information after restart
          } else {
            //Throw a warning or sth with your preferred logger
          }
        }

        operator fun get(@PropertyKey(resourceBundle = BUNDLE_NAME) key: String, vararg args: Any): String {
            val bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME, actualLocal)
            return MessageFormat.format(bundle.getString(key), *args)
        }

        fun createStringBinding(@PropertyKey(resourceBundle = BUNDLE_NAME) key: String, vararg args: Any): StringBinding {
            return Bindings.createStringBinding(Callable { get(key, *args) }, Settings.languageProperty())
        }
    }
}

fun main() {
  println("My translation: " + MyLang.createStringBinding("MyApp.MyTranslation").get())
  //The get() here is only to get the string for assign a property its not needed like in the example
}
```

If you need any explanations or its unclear. Just ask! Its just written down maybe I forgot something to explain.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and sorry for the late reply. It helped a lot and is also working in my existing UI. But what I don't get is how to change the language in the running app. For example, the default is SupportedLocale.ENGLISH and then in my app I have a button that changes the language to GERMAN with  MyLang.setLocale(SupportedLocale.GERMAN) but then the labels are still shown in English. Could you please help me here?

Comment: Another point that is unclear to me is the usage of `Settings.languageProperty()` in the `createStringBinding` function. In my code I removed it and it worked otherwise I get the error that `languageProperty` is unknown

Comment: OK your set local function is right. Did you bind the `createStringBinding` to a textProperty? e.g. for a menu item inside your view `menubutton {
             textProperty().bind(MyLang.createStringBinding("MyApp.MyTranslation"))}` ?

Comment: When I use the `textProperty().bind(MyLang.createStringBinding("MyApp.MyTranslation"))}` on a label it is not updating. I created also a itemViewModel and use the binding there but it is just updating when I trigger the `onRefresh()` function (I am using the workspace class of tornadofx)